# Any way to tell Kotlin compiler that prior callable function already did a check for null

Tags: kotlin, null-check

If I have a code fragment like

```
val myNullableString : String?
val resultingString = if (myNullableString.isNullOrBlank()) 
myNullDefaultString else String.format(myNullableString!!, someOtherString)
```

I have to use `myNullableString!!` in `String.format()` since the compiler would not be able to figure out that `isNullOrBlank()` includes a null-check. Is this correct or is there any way to tell the compiler that a function will infer that the instance is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin 1.3 introduced a concept called [contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts). From now on you can tell the compiler that a null check has been done. It has already been implemented for all necessary functions in the standard library (for `isNullOrBlank()` too).

So, your example would compile now without `!!`

```
val myNullableString: String? = null

val result = if (myNullableString.isNullOrBlank()) {
    "default"
} else {
    String.format(myNullableString, "hello") // myNullableString is smart-casted to String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t see any mentions that there is a way to tell such info to the compiler, but here is a workaround: having function returning null if string is empty and use let?.{} after that

```
inline fun String?.nullIfBlank(): String? = if (this?.isBlank() ?: true) null else this

val resultingString: String = myNullableString.nullIfBlank()?.let {
    String.format(it) 
} ?: myNullDefaultString
```

Comment: I think the code in your question is clear enough. Since you know `myNullableString` must not be null within the else case, it is safe to use !!. I would rather wait for the update instead of writing some extra function.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can perform smart cast from nullable type to non-nullable only after explicit check expression, like `myNullableString != null`